# Need help identifying a font

Tags: font-identification

I came across these images online. I cropped it to post here. I have tried WhatTheFont!, Identifont or WhatFontIs, but it cant find any similar font.

I specifically want a similar font which has the lower l,h or k as the images(see source as I cant post more links). More typography can be seen in the source as linked.

[image]

The sources of these images is available http://blog.hwtm.com/2012/07/gorgeous-first-lohri-celebration-bonfire-motif/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the creative director in the comments on your link, the script font is called Albemarle.

Comment: This is embarrassing. I should have checked that too. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: No problem. I was short with my answer, so I apologize.